# Spring XD Custom Module Development Maven Dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-xd

When developing Spring XD custom modules you need to specify spring-xd-module-parent as the parent project, however the most recent Spring XD version in maven central is 1.0.4, instead of 1.2.1. Is this an oversight or do I need to use a Spring repository for the XD dependenices?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same error, and to solve it I looked at maven based spring-xd modules examples on github and found the solution.
The `spring-xd-module-parent` is located in the spring repositories not in the maven central.
Add the following repository to your pom to solve the problem.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-io-release</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Yes I know it will work if you do this, but I was wanting to know if there was a reason why the dependencies weren't in Maven Central